# How to use CoffeeScript's built-in helper functions?

Tags: coffeescript

CoffeeScript comes with a few [helper functions](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/helpers.html). How to use them? `flatten(Array)` for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These functions seem to be intended for private use by the CoffeeScript compiler. It might be better to use a general-purpose library like [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) if you want these sort of features.

```
coffee> _ = require('underscore')
coffee> _.flatten [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: Exactly. `helpers.coffee` only exists so that the CoffeeScript compiler doesn't need external dependencies like Underscore.

Comment: just a note that in the coffee shell, _ is already used as a keyword that represents the previous value.  so use `u = require('underscore')` `u.flatten [1,2,3,[4,5]]`